# How to get the AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer of a Swift Object

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, owncloud, unsafemutablepointer

I'm currently the [owncloud iOS library](https://github.com/owncloud/ios-library) for an upload task of my Swift app.
It is written in Objective-C and requires me to pass an `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSProgress?>` to the [upload method](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.2/developer_manual/ios_library/examples.html#upload-a-file-with-background-session).

Say I create a new object like so

```
let progress: NSProgress? = NSProgress()
```

How can I get the `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSProgress?>` of this object in Swift?

I tried it the following way:

```
var progress: NSProgress? = NSProgress()
let unsafeAutoreleasingProgressPointer = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSProgress?>.init(&progress)
```

But I get an

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address = 0x15942320)

when executing the code. I would like to keep a reference to the progress object because I want to add an observer callback that tells me the upload progress in percent (as also demonstrated in the example link).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were 2 issues in fact.

We can create an `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSProgress?>` object like so:

```
let progress = NSProgress()
let progressPointer = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSProgress?>.init(&progress)
```

It's important to note that you have to keep the pointer around. If you create the pointer in a method, the reference to it will be lost as soon as we exit the method scope. This causes the

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS

exception. So your implementation might look like this:

```
class MyClass: NSObject {
    dynamic var progress: NSProgress = NSProgress()
    var progressPointer: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSProgress?> = nil

    override init(){
        //...
        //init non optional variables here
        super.init()
        progressPointer = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSProgress?>.init(&progress)
    }
}
```

In my case I did **Key-Value Observing** because I was using a third party Objective C dependency. Note that you have to put the `dynamic` keyword in front of the object you want to observe using KVO.

If you still get an

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS

exception, use the **Singleton pattern**.

Answer (score 5):

`AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer` is just a struct. All you have to do is create the pointer and then assign the value to its `memory` property.

```
var pointer = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSProgress>.init()
pointer.memory = progress!
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get a fatal error when I try your code: 

let progress: NSProgress? = NSProgress();

var progressPointer = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSProgress?>.init();

 progressPointer.memory = progress!;

I had to change the NSProgress type in the pointer to an Optional because the library requires this.